# How to set multiple package directories under setup.py

Tags: python, package, setup.py

Does anyone know how to set multiple package directories inside the `setup.py`

```
packages=['package_1', 'package_2'],
package_dir={??,??}
```

Taking in consideration that both packages are under different folders.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The `package_dir` option is just a dictionary mapping from package name to directory location relative to the distribution root. So you can just do:

```
package_dir={package_1:package1_dir, package_2:package2_dir}
```

Any subdirectories within these directories will also be checked recursively. According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html):

> A `package: dir` entry in the `package_dir` dictionary implicitly applies to all packages below `package`